# SQL - find a table row with the highest number being less than a specified number

Tags: sql

How can I efficiently find 1 table row that has the highest number in a column that is less than a specified (query) value?

**UPDATE**: based on the answer of @Gordon Linoff, then finding 1 table row should be the statement below? Is this the most efficient way?

```
select * from table1 where colname1 in 
   ( select max( colname1) from table1 where colname1 < 528188000 )
```

@Eric - mostly I am not lazy, at this late I hour maybe I was a bit lazy for a second ;-)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, databases contain *tables*, not *columns*.

Comment: You have _more_ than enough reputation to be writing a question with this little detail. VTC.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good and efficient. Especially, if there exists an index on `table1(colname1)`. It should be `=`, though, instead of `IN`, because your subquery cannot return multiple rows.

```
select * from table1 where colname1 =
   ( select max(colname1) from table1 where colname1 < 528188000 )
```

You say that you are looking for *one* row. So you consider it guaranteed that `colname1` values are unique in the table (maybe because there exists a unique constraint on that column). If so, it may be more efficient to *tell* the DBMS that you are looking for exactly one row. In standard SQL:

```
select *
from table1
where colname1 < 528188000
order by colname1 desc
fetch first row only;
```

Your DBMS may use another syntax. In SQL Server it's `TOP(1)`; in MySQL it's `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret "database" as table, then in standard SQL, you can do:

```
select max(col)
from t
where col < @value
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Yeah, a table row ;-). Based on your reply, I guess this is the right query to find a row. Is it the most efficient way?

Comment: @tm1701 . . . If you have an index on `(col)` then most databases should "do the right thing".  However, that depends on the optimizer and database.